# Deployment Methods

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I am an experienced ASP.NET developer and new to SharePoint.
I have to start a project where I am supposed to create some workflows, alter search features and provide viewer for Auto-CAD files.

Is there any way to package all of these thing and create one file installation?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to working with SharePoint -- you'll find certain things much easier (no need to re-invent things like authentication and backup) but other things will be very frustrating (why can't I just easily add some custom code here to do x...)

Your question is quite vague, but I think what you might be looking for is creating a solution in Visual Studio that you can deploy as a packaged set of files to your SharePoint installation.

I would really highly recommend doing a short class on SharePoint, it should be just what you need to get up to speed since you're already familiar with ASP.NET -- I actually like the videos by Christopher Harrison and Chris Johnson on Microsoft Virtual Academy: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start

The videos can be a bit labored because they jump back and forth between a remote dev machine and the local desktops they're using for presentations, but I think that level and speed of content coverage will be perfect considering your previous experience. There is also a course on advanced solutions (Christopher Harrison and Tom Resing) which I found quite helpful.

I also see you listed apps as one of your tags, and I would just throw in a word of advice that SharePoint Apps are fairly different than typical ASP or Server Side development and you might need to do some homework before you begin any serious work – but the videos outlined above cover the App model in a good deal of detail as well.

-Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you very much John the two cources you pointed are already in my to do list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad. What i understand you want package 3 different things in one package Worflows, Search feature and Auto-Cad.

To view Auto-Cad file you need to deploy the a connector(AutoDesk Valut).

For the Workflow, you have two options

- [Use SharePoint deisgner and save the workflow as template and use it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316(v=office.15).aspx)
- [- Or You can use Visual Studio to develop the workflows.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199(v=office.15).aspx)

Now for the search feature alteration, its depend what you want. Some time just few settings change, adding a crawl rule, maanged search proptery etc.

I dont think you can combine all 3 in one solution file. You may combine workflow and search alteration in one feature but AUTOCad required different steps.

But i would keep all 3 separate.